# I need to get value from input with id of selected item and return them to controller

Tags: php, laravel, request

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to get value of input with selected element's id.

When I am trying to get input value of quantity in controller it's actually empty.

Here is my code.

collect.blade.php

```
@foreach($reagentcard as $r)
                            <tr>
                            <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $r->casnumber }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $r->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $r->description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $r->classification }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $r->manname }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $r->incomedate}} </td>
                            <td>{{ $r->expirationdate}} </td>
                            <td>{{ $r->quantity }} </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity"></td>
                            @if($message = Session::get('info'))
                            <strong style="color:red">{{ $message }}</strong><br>
                            @endif
                            @if($message = Session::get('error'))
                            <strong style="color:red">{{ $message }}</strong><br>
                            @endif
                            <td><a href=" {{ route('collect',['id' => $r -> id]) }}"><button> Collect </button></a> </td>
                        @endforeach
```

controller.php

```
public function collectReagent($id, Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $takedate = Carbon::now();
    $reagentcard = ReagentCard::where('id',$id)->first();
    $test = $request->route('quantity');
    return view('test',compact('test', 'id'));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `@if($message = ` `=` assigns a value, `==` compares

Comment: "_I am trying to get value of input with selected element's id_" Your input doesn't have an `id` attribute. Using `<a href` doesn't submit the form/input elements, use a `<form>` and a submit button. Your controller method doesn't actually ask for the input's value.

Comment: When i tried to do what u suggested the id was always the same value

Comment: Here's the documentation on [Interacting With The Request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#interacting-with-the-request)

Comment: Nesting `button` into `a` is also not allowed n HTML, you need to decide whether you want to use the one _or_ the other.

Comment: And PHP itself is not able to process multiple external parameters of the same name correctly (and I doubt laravel does something on its own to fix that?), unless "array syntax" is used in the parameter name. So if you have `<input ... name="quantity">` in a loop there and all part of one single form, then the last of those submitted values would overwrite all previous ones. In such a case, you need to use something like `name="quantity[]"`, _then_ PHP will create an array out of all the values passed under that name.